# Wix 3.5 - change/repair does not request elevation

Tags: wix, uac

I'm having a strange problem with WIX: when I install/uninstall my package, the UAC is invoked correctly and everything works fine. However, when I go through change/repair scenarios, the installer does not request UAC Elevation and the machine-wide settings are not updated (just not changed; even the feature state remains the same next time I run the installer).

When I run the msiexec already elevated, everything works just fine.

the InstallScope is set to perMachine

Answer (score 1):

If you launch from Programs and Features your install is automatically elevated. It sounds like your install is behaving correctly when done through Install but not Change. Check the verbose log to see the action states of your Components. Chances are the verbose log file will show differences.